# PHP checkbox validation, if else issue

Tags: php, post, checkbox

I have a checkbox in my HTML file:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="kopia" name="kopia" class="form-input" value="0">
```

I'm trying to pass to the PHP file (via AJAX) a couple of values, one of them is a boolean value created by a checkbox (simplified):

```
name: "kopia"
value: document.getElementById("kopia").checked
```

If I check via console, it returns `true` if checked and `false` if unchecked.

```
document.getElementById("kopia").checked
```

If I check via PHP file, it behaves the same:

```
echo $_POST['kopia']
```

But when I write something like this:

```
$checkbox = $_POST['kopia'];
if ($checkbox){
    echo "hey";
} else {echo "bye";}
```

It always returns "hey", no matter if the checkbox was checked or not. I don't get it. Even if I make something like this:

```
$checkbox = $_POST['kopia'];
if ($checkbox){
    echo $checkbox;
} else {echo "bye";}
```

It never returns "bye", no matter if the box was checked or not, but returns `true` if checked and `false` if unchecked. This thing has already stolen a couple of hours and that's a couple of hours too much. Any idea, hint?

Comment: I assume you omitted some JS that changes the value. `$_POST` values will always be strings in PHP so your `if` is expecting boolean.  Try `if ($checkbox == "true")` Or use `0` and `1`.

Comment: `if ($checkbox == "true")` that's a string equaling "true"; boolean's `if ($checkbox == true)` @AbraCadaver two different animals ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Re-read my comment.  You won't get boolean values in `$_POST` vars. That's why when OP `echo $checkbox;` they get "true" or "false"

Comment: can you show your ajax code

Comment: @AbraCadaver Sure, yet you wrote *"Try if ($checkbox == "true")"* - that's just it; that isn't boolean `true|false`. Unless the value of the checkbox is `value="true"`. They have `value="0"`; the answer to this is `isset()` and with an optional `&& $var=="x"` type of thing. Unless I'm having a *blonde moment* lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think you are having a blond moment :-) They are passing the var `kopia` with the value of `document.getElementById("kopia").checked` which is boolean in JS but when it gets to PHP via POST it is string "true" or string "false".

Comment: Can you show how you're passing the value with AJAX?

Comment: @AbraCadaver *Ah,* I see what you mean now. I guess I should go to the hairdresser now. I want my 'ol hair colour back.

Comment: Problem solved. As I already wrote, I didn't know (i'm more js, don't know much about php), that $_POST values are always strings. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are passing `true` or `false` in `$_POST['kopia']` via the return of `document.getElementById("kopia").checked`, however `$_POST` values are strings in PHP.  So both string `"true"` and string `"false"` will evaluate to boolean `true` in your current if condition.  You can check the string value:

```
$checkbox = $_POST['kopia'];
if ($checkbox == "true"){
    echo $checkbox;
} else {
    echo "bye";
}
```

Or you can convert them to a boolean, see [PHP: Validate Filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) (thanks to [Sysix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7387397/sysix)):

```
$checkbox = filter_var($_POST['kopia'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```

Or if you set `$_POST['kopia']` to `0` or `1`, those strings will be evaluated correctly in your current if condition.

Or you could abandon the JS value switching and just check if `$_POST['kopia']` exists (only when checked):

```
if(isset($_POST['kopia'])) {
    echo "hey";
} else {
    echo "bye";
}
```

Comment: That's the thing! I'm more of a js guy, so I didn't know that $_POST values are turned to strings. Thanks!

Comment: he can also transform the string into a boolean with `$checkbox = filter_var($_POST['kopia'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);`

Comment: @Sysix: Right on, I always forget that one.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a simple check like this:

```
$isChecked = !empty($_POST['kopia']) ? true : false;
if($isChecked){
    echo 'Checked';
}
else{
    echo 'Not checked';
}
```

empty checks both isset and if 0 it equals false, if 1 it equals true and if not set it equals false.

Hopes this helps.

Comment: Except it will never be empty given OP's description and code.